# Setting up multiple platforms in one single firebase project

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I'm getting started with Firebase and I am looking at the best way to setup projects. I have an Android and iOS app.

**I am wondering whether to**

1. Setup a single project for both Android and iOS or
2. To create two different projects one for Android and iOS respectively.

What is usually the right setup? Are there any advantages of doing one over the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that your Android and iOS are the same app, just on different platforms.

The intended and recommended use is for all your apps that share the same data and configuration to exist in the same project.

There is almost no advantage to splitting them into different projects, as you will end up having to put extra effort into configuring one of the apps to access the other project's data.  It doesn't make any sense unless you have some extreme requirements that make it difficult for them to exist in the same project.

Comment: how can we configure the firebase project if our aim is to use single app for different platforms as you said. I am using Flutter for fronted and Firebase but I don't know how to configure firebase project (single) in order to make it work on web, ios and android platform. and also my Flutter project will be same for all the platforms no different project for different platform everything in single project .